# How to solve errors while compiling discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have created a bot for discord using python 3.8 and everything is working fine but when I send the message || add reaction to any post, I got the error `cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object` in the compiler while the bot is still working and online and bot is also executing the error exception in the discord which I have sets up manually `An Error Occurred`, I send the message again and the compiler logs the same error again.
any idea to solve it?

CODE:

```
class Exp(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    async def process_xp(self, message):
        xp, lvl, xplock = db.record("SELECT XP, Level, XPLock FROM exp WHERE UserID = ?", message.author.id)

        if datetime.utcnow() > datetime.fromisoformat(xplock):
            await self.add_xp(message, xp, lvl)

    async def add_xp(self, message, xp, lvl):
        xp_to_add = randint(10, 20)
        new_lvl = int(((xp + xp_to_add) // 42) ** 0.55)

        db.execute("UPDATE exp SET XP = XP + ?, Level = ?, XPLock = ? WHERE UserID = ?",
                   xp_to_add, new_lvl, (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=60)).isoformat(), message.author.id)

        if new_lvl > lvl:
            await self.levelup_channel.send(f"Congrats {message.author.mention} - you reached level {new_lvl:,}!")
            await self.check_lvl_rewards(message, new_lvl)

    async def check_lvl_rewards(self, message, lvl):
        if lvl >= 50:  # Red
            if (new_role := message.guild.get_role(841660969991195158)) not in message.author.roles:
                await message.author.add_roles(new_role)
                await message.author.remove_roles(message.guild.get_role(841661523859588840))
```

[image]

`Code in db.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guilds (
    GuildID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    Prefix text DEFAULT "+"
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS exp (
    UserID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    XP integer DEFAULT 0,
    Level integer DEFAULT 0,
    XPLock text DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mutes (
    UserID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    RoleIDs text,
    EndTime text
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS starboard (
    RootMessageID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    StarMessageID integer,
    Stars integer DEFAULT 1
);
```

`Code db.py`

```
    from os.path import isfile
from sqlite3 import connect

from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger

DB_PATH = "./data/db/database.db"
BUILD_PATH = "./data/db/build.sql"

cxn = connect(DB_PATH, check_same_thread=False)
cur = cxn.cursor()

def with_commit(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        commit()

    return inner

@with_commit
def build():
    if isfile(BUILD_PATH):
        scriptexec(BUILD_PATH)

def commit():
    cxn.commit()

def autosave(sched):
    sched.add_job(commit, CronTrigger(second=0))

def close():
    cxn.close()

def field(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))

    if (fetch := cur.fetchone()) is not None:
        return fetch[0]

def record(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))

    return cur.fetchone()

def records(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))

    return cur.fetchall()

def column(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))

    return [item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()]

def execute(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))

def multiexec(command, valueset):
    cur.executemany(command, valueset)

def scriptexec(path):
    with open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as script:
        cur.executescript(script.read())
```

Comment: What exactly is `db`? What sql are you using

Comment: @Ceres I am using SQLite

Comment: Actually you have a plugin error if you are not using intellij Idea Commercial because on student-license.jar you are not allowed to use SQLite and it will always give access denied error, to solve this issue just install external SQL Server and connect to it.

Comment: @Саша Solved testing with VStudio + SQLite

Answer (score 1):

You are probably encountering an error when the query `SELECT XP, Level, XPLock FROM exp WHERE UserID = ?` returns None, this probably happens because your database is empty or has no row with the selected user id.

I would suggest changing the row:

```py
xp, lvl, xplock = db.record("SELECT XP, Level, XPLock FROM exp WHERE UserID = ?", message.author.id)
```

to something like:

```py
result = db.record("SELECT XP, Level, XPLock FROM exp WHERE UserID = ?", message.author.id)
if result is None:
    handle_new_user_id(message.author.id)
    return
xp, lvl, xplock = result
```

this way you only unpack values when the query return some row.
The `handle_new_user_id` should do something for user ids that are not yet in the database

Comment: It gives the same error, I think I have selected wrong ID's for channels and Users roles.

Comment: can you post the error here? now line 51 has no unpacking operation so the error can not be the same.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Exp' object has no attribute 'bot'

Comment: So it is not the same error as before, can you post the complete traceback?

Comment: I reversed the code and I found the actual error is happening because the db structure is not initialized, maybe access denied or something... I am writing the basic bot from scratch to test with db initializer

Comment: Yes, sounds reasonable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232237/discussion-between-ali-baba-and-matteo-zanoni).